# What is a robust alternative to sshfs (which has been recently orphaned)?

Tags: sshfs

According to https://github.com/libfuse/sshfs, `sshfs` is now an orphaned project, with no active maintainers.

Is there a good, safe, robust alternative, one can use to mount remote filesystems?

Comment: Requests for product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they attract low quality, opinionated and spam answers, and the answers become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe the business problem you are working on, the research you have done, and the steps taken so far to solve it.

Comment: @djdomi The "business problem" is mounting a remote filesystem. `sshfs` is a standard tool for this (shipped by default in most major Linux distros). I think it's been around for a very long time and people know what it does. The point is that quite recently (and surprisingly) it's been unmaintained. Though I realize an open-ended software recommendation discussion can be endless, that's not what I'm asking here. I have a concrete problem (mount remote filesystems) and am asking for one, robust & safe way of solving it.

Comment: that ends up on a recommondation. And it does not tell the Original issue you have. SSHFS is just a option to mount a remote target - but why you do so, for what purpose is still a secret. i would suggest that you edit your question